# making a two column text block in ms-word with knitr

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to recreate an existing letter, for bulk generation. I'm using  knitr and a reference document in the YAML for styling of the output doc. The whole thing has gone pretty well, except for the two column address block. I have tried kable, pasting the strings with \t tabs between, and playing with the formatting of the reference doc. No dice.

This is the output I want (obviously without the underscores...) :

> Date 
>   Client: Foo & Bar____________________ Client's Client: Bar 
>   Address: 1234 Blah St._______________ ID: Numbersnumbers 
>  More
>   Address: City, St. Zip____________ Last Piece: of Info 
>    Body - in
>   paragraph form.

The problem is that the left column is variable length so the right is not justified. Also, kable has a required column label and when I used "nbsp", it still left a dividing line above the block.

Is there a good way to do this that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [ReporteRs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ReporteRs/index.html) to generate the documents. You have to build the components of the document (and its formatting) in the R script instead of having an Rmd file, but you can still specify a reference doc for additional styling like headers/footers. You also get a LOT of flexibility for tables, which is cool.

Comment: Would be great if you could share a working solution here and not just a link to other resources.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to try a package that isn't on CRAN yet, you can install the `Gmisc` package from GitHub. (`Gmisc` version 1.1 is on CRAN, but the tools you need to render the docx are in version 1.2, which hasn't been released yet)

```
library(devtools)
install_github("gforge/Gmisc")
```

`Gmisc` gives you the option of knitting a docx_document that will preserve HTML formatting.  This gives you a lot more flexibility of formatting than the usual Word output.  The file will render as an HTML file, but if you right click and open it with MS Word, you'll see the formatting is preserved.

````
---
title: ""
output: Gmisc::docx_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(pixiedust)
```

Date: `r format(Sys.Date(), format = "%B %d, %Y")`

```{r, echo=FALSE}
DFrame <- 
  data.frame(
    left = c("Client: Foo & Bar",
             "Address: 1234 Blah St",
             "More Address: City, State ZIP"),
    right = c("Client's Client: Bar",
              "ID: Numbers numbers",
              "Last Piece: of Info"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dust(DFrame) %>%
  sprinkle_colnames("", "") %>%
  sprinkle(cols = 1, width = 3, width_units = "in")%>%
  sprinkle_print_method("html")
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Do you know if a reference doc can be used with Grmd? I tried it earlier today and the formatting didn't carry over. Figured it was probably user error.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by reference doc.

Comment: knitr for word allows you to specify a style doc in the YAML like this: 
---<br>
title: <br>
output:<br> 
  word_document:<br> 
    reference_docx: reference2.docx<br>
---<br>
It allows for more detailed formatting and makes putting headers/footers in the output pretty east

Comment: This is something I'm not familiar with. You may want to contact the `Gmisc` maintainer. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I ended up abandoning rmarkdown altogether and using ReporteRs, but for less stringent applications in the future, I'll revisit Grmd.