# R markdown word output, put kable and figure side by side

Tags: r, plot, markdown, knitr, kable

Is there a way to put a kable (from the knitr package) and a plot side by side in the output (word output)?

I have this in my code:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
res$actzoneBar
kable(res$actzone)
````

Where the first one is a plot, and the second one a table with just 2 columns. So they would perfectly fit side by side (and that is also prettier in the final file).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: hello check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753897/2-column-section-in-r-markdown

Comment: isn't that only for html?

Comment: oh i didnt see the `word output` there s this but it's not in markdown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731204/making-a-two-column-text-block-in-ms-word-with-knitr

Comment: I haven't use `reporteR` yet, but it looks great for word output. Otherwise, you may ask your question to the `pandoc` community.